# Can I use SPFx 2019 webpart to 2016 on-premises?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

I have created SPFx webpart for SharePoint Online and 2019 on-premises. Now I want to run same webpart on Sharepoint 2016 on-premises. 
So my question is that Can I run same webpart on 2016 by doing some minor changes on that or Do I need to create new webpart for 2016 environment?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from this article:

> Because SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2016 have different release
>   cycles for new capabilities, they also have different capabilities
>   when it comes to the SharePoint Framework. SharePoint Online always
>   uses the latest version of the SharePoint Framework, but SharePoint
>   2016 only supports the version that matches the server-side
>   dependencies of the deployed packages.
>
> SharePoint 2016 Feature Pack 2 supports SharePoint Framework
>   client-side web parts hosted on classic SharePoint pages built by
>   using the SharePoint Framework v1.1.0. This means that when you are
>   targeting the SharePoint 2016 platform, you need to use the SharePoint
>   Framework v1.1.0 due to the server-side version dependencies.
>
> If you are planning to use the same client-side web parts in both
>   SharePoint 2016 and in SharePoint Online, you need to use the
>   SharePoint Framework v1.1.0 as your baseline version to ensure that
>   the web part works in both environments.
>
> Starting from version 1.3, the SharePoint Framework Yeoman generator
>   supports scaffolding solutions that use both the latest version of the
>   SharePoint Framework meant for use with SharePoint Online, and
>   solutions that can be used with SharePoint on-premises based on the
>   v1.1.0 of the SharePoint Framework. You don't need to install a
>   separate version of the SharePoint Framework Yeoman generator to
>   scaffold solutions meant for use with SharePoint on-premises.

More information is here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2016-support